# why sort function of STL is not working?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

A set of numbers will be passed as input. Also the redefined relationship of the digits 0-9 in ascending order will be passed as input. Based on the redefined relationship, the set of numbers must be listed in ascending order.
Sample I/O

Input:

```
20 50 11 121

9231476058
```

Output:

```
50 11 20 121
```

The program which i wrote having an error about which i am not aware of. so, please help me in debugging it.

Program specification:

1.) I created one adjacency list for grouping the numbers on the basis of their     number of digits(50 11 20 grouped at index 2 and 121 at index 3)

2.)For sorting them i have used standard template library sort function. I have passed the following parameters

```
list<int> *lst=new list<int>[10];       //adjacency list

void sortg(list<int> *lst,int *arr1)
{
    static int *arr=arr1;
    struct fnct
    {
        int digi;

        fnct(int digi)
        {
            this->digi=digi;
        }
        bool operator()(int val1,int val2)
        {
            while(digi>0)  // is the number of digits of the passed arguments
            {
                //logic for sorting. here i have used local arry "*arr" which i
                //have declared static
            }
        }
    };

    for(int con=9;con>=0;--con)      //count for the rows of adjacency list
    {
        if( (*(lst+con)).size()>0 )     // for finding out a valid list
        {
            sort((lst+con)->begin(),(lst+con)->end(),fnct(con));

        }
    }
}
```

The error which i got is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,from prog.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void
std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with
_RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<int>; _Compare =                  
__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<sortg(std::list<int>*, int*)::fnct>]':
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4716:78:   required from 'void              

std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter =   

std::_List_iterator<int>;    _Compare = sortg(std::list<int>*, int*)::fnct]'
prog.cpp:124:63:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: error: no match for       'operator-  

'    (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<int>' and   

'std::_List_iterator<int>')
 std::__lg(__last - __first)     

*2,/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:1968:22: note:      

'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const    

std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'
 std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,


                 "Lines are removed from here"
                  ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/vector:65:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/random.h:34,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/random:49,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62,
             from prog.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_bvector.h:208:3: note: std::ptrdiff_t   std::operator-(const std::_Bit_iterator_base&, const std::_Bit_iterator_base&)
operator-(const _Bit_iterator_base& __x, const _Bit_iterator_base& __y)
^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_bvector.h:208:3: 

note:no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<int>' to   
'const std::_Bit_iterator_base&'
```

Since this error is lengthy i have removed some lines from in between of it

Comment: `std::sort` doesn't work on lists (bi-directional iterator types). Use `list.sort()` instead.

Comment: You can blame C++ templates for the horrid error message.

Comment: Okay, so clearly you already know about `std::list`, and that you should use it instead of implementing your own linked list. So why are you using a heap-allocated array instead of `std::vector`?

Comment: @Sneftel will it be having any effect on performance of above program? though i know their uses but i don't have much knowledge about their effects on performance.

Comment: You do realize that your functor does nothing and is missing a `return` statement, right? Even if `sort` worked, you'd get garbage results because of the undefined behavior of your functor not returning a value.

Comment: @Ganesh No. `std::vector` is an exponentially-growing dynamic array, nothing more. If you give it a fixed size, it will never have poorer performance than a raw array. (For that matter, it's fairly likely to give you better performance than `std::list` for adjacency lists.)

Comment: @Cornstalks:sorry to say but i thought that showing the logic for sorting will be redundant for this post that's why i have removed it.

Comment: Aside: you should usually use `lst[con]` instead of `*(lst+con)`. Also, use `x->y` rather than `(*x).y`.

Comment: @Ganesh: I see. Well, on StackOverflow, it's expected that people will post a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in line

```
 sort((lst+con)->begin(),(lst+con)->end(),fnct(con));
```

says

```
 In instantiation of 'void
std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with
_RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<int>; _Compare =                  
__gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<sortg(std::list<int>*, int*)::fnct>]'
```

Now, List is built as a doubly linked list (hence iteration in both directions) with its primary feature being the support for constant time insert and erase operations. But Random Access ? No.

So, the error message says that sort needs RandomAccessIterator which List Iterator isn't (It is Bidirectional iterator which is expected as list is implemented as a doubly linked list).

So, use the member function sort to do this.

```
(*(lst+con).)sort(fnct(con));  // Use it as appropriate
```

Comment: but how the RandomAccessIterator are used over here and how to implement them?