# How to sort std::list of pairs by key?

Tags: c++, sorting, std, std-pair, stdlist

I would like to sort a `std::list<std::pair<string, int>>` by the *key* as well as by the *value* in two separate functions.

I am getting an error that says:

```
error: reference to non-static member function must be called
    sort(test.begin(), test.end(), sortByVal);
```

The code

```
class Test 
{
    std::list<pair<std::string, int>> test;

public:
    void sortbykey()
    {
        sort(test.begin(), test.end(), sortByVal);
    }

    bool sortByVal(const std::pair<std::string, int>& a, const std::pair<std::string, int>& b)
    {
        return (a.first < b.first);
    }
};
```

Comment: Please don't desribe code, instead, provide [mcve]. If you have troubles with class members, put them in a class in the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why sort function of STL is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965367/why-sort-function-of-stl-is-not-working)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort#Parameters) required to have the iterator passed to be *[Legacy Random AccessIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator)*. But the [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Member_types) has *[Legacy Bidirectional Iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list#Member_types)*, which is why the error.

---

On the other hand, the `std::list` has a member function [`std::list<T>::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort), which would be prefered way to go, if you insist the container must be `std::list`.

Since you need to sort by the `first` of the pairs, you need to pass a custom comparator (or lambda) to it.

Meaning you need

```
void sortbykey()
{
    test.sort([](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs.first < rhs.first; });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The iterator has to be a random access iterator. A `list`-iterator isn't.

Comment: Excellent!  And the comparison function must be static or free-standing as Paul explained.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `std::vector`, and make the comparison function static

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Test {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> test;

  public:
    void sortbykey() {
        sort(test.begin(), test.end(), sortByVal);
    }

    static bool sortByVal(const std::pair<std::string, int> &a,
                          const std::pair<std::string, int> &b) {
        return (a.first < b.first);
    }
};
```